# ¿Se puede personalizar un AlertDialog con botones y que estos funcionen como los por defecto?

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

En mi `XML` le seteo la vista con 2 botones (Cancelar,Aceptar), y cree mi propia clase de `AlertDialog` y `AlertDialog.Builder` para que este sea el mismo en toda la aplicacion.
La cuestion es que busco que mi botón Cancelar y Aceptar funcione igual que el AlertDialog.Builder.SetNegativeButton(); y el AlertDialog.Builder.SetPositiveButton(); ,que al tocar el botón se cierre el AlertDialog.

En https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html?hl=es-419

Dice

> Descartar un diálogo Cuando el usuario toca cualquiera de los botones
>   de acción creados con un AlertDialog.Builder, el sistema descarta el
>   diálogo por ti.
>
> El sistema también descarta el diálogo cuando el usuario toca un
>   elemento en una lista de diálogo, excepto cuando la lista usa botones
>   de selección o casillas de verificación.

**Mi XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gris">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/AlertDialog_rv_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AlertDialog_Negativo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/verde"
            android:text="Cancelar"
            android:background="@null" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AlertDialog_Positivo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/verde"
            android:text="Aceptar"
            android:background="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Mi Clase `AlertDialog` y `AlertDialog.Builder`

```
public class myAlertDialog : AlertDialog
{
    protected myAlertDialog(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override void Dismiss()
    {
        base.Dismiss();
    }

    public class myBuilder : Builder
    {
        public Context context;
        private List<IListeable> list;
        private Button Positivo;
        private Button Negativo;
        private RecyclerView RecyclerView;
        private TextView Titulo;
        private myAlertDialogAdapter adapter;

        private Seleccion TipoSeleccion;

        public myBuilder(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            this.context = context;

            //Default seleccion Multiple
            this.TipoSeleccion = Seleccion.Multiple;

            //Inicializar
            list = new List<IListeable>();

            //Creo la vista
            var view = LayoutInflater.From(context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.myAlertDialog, null, false);

            RecyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.AlertDialog_rv_data);
            Positivo = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AlertDialog_Positivo);
            Negativo = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AlertDialog_Negativo);

            base.SetView(view);


        }

        public new myAlertDialog Show()
        {              
            return base.Show() as myAlertDialog;
        }

    }
}

public enum Seleccion
{
    Ninguno,
    Simple,
    Multiple
}
```

y si lo declaro en mi AppCompatActivity

```
        myAlertDialog alert;
        myAlertDialog.myBuilder builder = new myAlertDialog.myBuilder(this);
        builder.SetTitle("Categorias");
        //Asignar item y forma de seleccion
        builder.SetItems(items, Seleccion.Multiple);
        alert = builder.Show();
```

Podrían decirme si esto es posible? o algún ejemplo que pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 5):

Te muestro como se podría crear un cuadro de dialogo personalizado en Android Studio con Java.
Te paso enlace a la referencia del sitio [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) de como hacerlo.

1). Nuestro Layout personalizado.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/header_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="#3a33ff"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:hint="@string/username" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="@string/password"/>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_fire"
            android:text="@string/fire"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

2). Creamos un método para crear nuestro Cuadro de diálogo personalizado

```
public AlertDialog createCustomDialog(){
        final AlertDialog alertDialog;
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        // Inflar y establecer el layout para el dialogo
        // Pasar nulo como vista principal porque va en el diseño del diálogo
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
        //builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
        Button btnFire = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_fire);
        Button btnCancel = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        builder.setView(v);
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        // Add action buttons
                btnFire.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // Aceptar
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                );
                btnCancel.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                );
        return alertDialog;
```

---

3). A la hora de llamarlo...

```
createCustomDialog().show();
```

---

Y una captura de como quedaría..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

P.d. Creo que es esto lo que buscas. Además también creo que ya te han dado una buena respuesta de ello. Solamente te lo paso todo dentro del mismo método para que lo tengas más claro. Saludos!!

Comment: si ya logre hacer ese tipo de cuadro de diálogos, lo que buscaba es que al crear mi propia clase de dialogo funcione siempre igual con los botones y los metodos que le ponga.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que estas buscando es sobreescribir los metodos del AlertDialog.Builder. al extender de este puedes sobreescribir el setNegativeButton, setNeutralButton y el setPositiveButton.

disculpa si no es, lo que pasa es que leyendo los demas y viendo que les dices que eso no es.. solo me queda suponer que esto es lo que estas buscando

```
public class AlertBuilderCustom extends AlertDialog.Builder {
protected AlertBuilderCustom(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public AlertDialog.Builder setPositiveButton(int textId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
    return super.setPositiveButton(textId, listener);
}

@Override
public AlertDialog.Builder setNegativeButton(int textId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
    return super.setNegativeButton(textId, listener);
}

@Override
public AlertDialog.Builder setNeutralButton(int textId, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
    return super.setNeutralButton(textId, listener);
}
```

}

despues de sobreescribirlos ya al final le puedes dar la instruccion de dismiss como los demas te han indicado.

saludos y buena energia :)

Comment: el código de las respuestas debe ser en texto, de lo contrario el OP debería copiar linea a linea; cuando hayas pegado tu código seleccionalo y dale clic al ícono de `{}`

Comment: Vale Alfredo :) apenas estoy aprendiendo a interactuar en esta pagina. lo siento

Comment: no hay problema saludos y sigue apoyando

Answer (score 0):

Hace unos dias lo hice para unas aplicaciones:

Primero crea el XML del diseño:

res/layout/custom_dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Cerrar sesion"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Seguro desea salir del app?"
        android:textColor="#757575"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btncancel"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_stroke_outlined"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="No"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:elevation="8dp"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnok"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_red"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:text="Si, salir"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:elevation="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Los errores de **android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_red"** , **android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_stroke_outlined"** y **android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_white"**

Se solucionan agregando estos xml para hacer las esquinas curvas y el color que queremos:

android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_red"

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#dd0207"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_white"

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_stroke_outlined"

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#dd0207"/>
</shape>
```

Codigo Java

```
private void alertInfoLogout(){
    ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

//botones de la vista personalizada
Button btnok, btncancel;

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, viewGroup, false); //R.layout.custom_dialog es nuestra vista dialog personalizada
    builder.setCancelable(false); //si queremos que al presionar fuera del dialog se cierre
    builder.setView(view1);

    btnok = view1.findViewById(R.id.btnok); //relacionamos id con elemento
    btncancel = view1.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); //acciones de cada boton del dialog

    btnok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    btncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda!

Answer (score -1):

Si se puede personalizar un `AlertDialog`.

En este caso obtienes las referencias de los botones, a estos botones puedes asignarles un listener:

```
 Positivo = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AlertDialog_Positivo);
 Negativo = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AlertDialog_Negativo);

Positivo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Botón positivo.
        alertDialog.dismiss();

    }
});

Negativo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Botón negativo.

    }
});
```

---

Basado en tu código este sería un ejemplo que crea un `AlertDialog` personalizado:

```
private void createCustomDialog(){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    //Load Layout custom_alertdialog.xml
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alertdialog, null);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    Button btnNegative = (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.AlertDialog_Negativo);
    Button btnPositive = (Button) promptView.findViewById(R.id.AlertDialog_Positivo);

    btnNegative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("AlertDialog", "btnNegative");
            alertDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    btnPositive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("AlertDialog", "btnPositive");

        }
    });

    alertDialog.setView(promptView);
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: claro, eso es lo que ya conseguí lograr, hice varios así, y ahora lo que buscaba es que envés de hacer un SetPositiveButton o SetNegativeButton, o de la forma que me mostras, hacer uno propio y que funcionen igual o mas o menos parecido. faltaría lograr que se "cierre el AlertDialog".

Comment: para que se cierre usa:   alertDialog.dismiss();

Comment: claro de la forma en que lo hiciste si funcionaria, quiero saber si se puede hacer algo parecido a lo que hice, de tener el propio AlertDialog customizado, y que se abra siempre igual, capaz no se puede, es como la primera vez que intento hacer una vista asi

Comment: Si se puede definitivamente.

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.